# I want perform calculations "Add" by extension string. How can do it?

Tags: java, android

I have 1 `EditText` and 4 buttons.

```
EditText: Show result
Button1: Number 1
Button2: Number 2
Button3: Operation "+"
Button3: Result "="
```

I want when press 1 + 1 + 2 + ... = Result.

So How Can do this ?

Comment: please post what (code) you've tried.. have you created onClickListeners for buttons?

Comment: I posted my code bellow

Comment: it's not an answer, please *edit* your question to add that code

Answer (score 0):

i think your are trying to do postfix evalution of the string.
[look at this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-evaluation/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I has performed :)